# JOptionPane Dialog Determine if Close Button was Clicked

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to create a dialog with a checkbox and a combobox. This is what I have:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("My checkbox");

JLabel modeLabel = new JLabel("Select mode:");
String[] modes = {"A", "B", "C"};
JComboBox<String> modesComboBox = new JComboBox<>(modes);
JPanel modePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
modePanel.add(modeLabel);
modePanel.add(modesComboBox);

JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
dialogPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(dialogPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
dialogPanel.add(checkBox);
dialogPanel.add(modePanel);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dialogPanel);
```

How do I determine whether the Close (i.e., "X") button or the OK button was clicked? I need to know which one of these two buttons caused the dialog to close.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)) (or overloaded equivalents) to get an `int` returned that reports yes, no or cancelled.

Calling `showConfirmDialog`..

> Brings up a dialog with the options Yes, No and Cancel; with the title, Select an Option.
> **Parameters:**
> `parentComponent` - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the `parentComponent` has no `Frame`, a default `Frame` is used
> `message` - the `Object` to display
> **Returns:**
> an `integer` **indicating the option selected by the user**

### Edit

On closer inspection, it becomes apparent this task needs both a confirmation dialog and an option dialog. Here is a complete example that reports the results of the user choices to the console.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class OptionSelection {

    public OptionSelection() {
        int result;
        String[] modes = {"A", "B", "C"};
        result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null,
                "Modes",
                "Select mode",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                modes,
                "B"
        );
        if (result == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("User canceled mode selection");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result: " + modes[result]);
        }
        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Are you now, or have you ever?",
                "Declaration",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("User says YES!");
        } else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("User says NO!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("User canceled");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> new OptionSelection();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```